# Puppet agent hangs and eventually gives a memory allocation error

Tags: performance, vagrant, puppet

I'm using puppet as a provisioner for Vagrant, and am coming across an issue where Puppet will hang for an extremely long time when I do a "vagrant provision". Building the box from scratch using "vagrant up" doesn't seem to be a problem, only subsequent provisions.

If I turn puppet debug on and watch where it hangs, it seems to stop at various, seemingly arbitrary, points the first of which is:

```
Info: Applying configuration version '1401868442'
Debug: Prefetching yum resources for package
Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm --version'
Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -qa --nosignature --nodigest --qf '%{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%    {EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n''
```

Executing this command on the server myself returns immediately.

Eventually, it gets past this and continues. Using the summary option, I get the following, after waiting for a very long time for it to complete:

```
Debug: Finishing transaction 70191217833880
Debug: Storing state
Debug: Stored state in 9.39 seconds
Notice: Finished catalog run in 1493.99 seconds
Changes:
        Total: 2
Events:
      Failure: 2
      Success: 2
        Total: 4
Resources:
        Total: 18375
      Changed: 2
       Failed: 2
      Skipped: 35
  Out of sync: 4
Time:
         User: 0.00
       Anchor: 0.01
     Schedule: 0.01
      Yumrepo: 0.07
       Augeas: 0.12
      Package: 0.18
         Exec: 0.96
      Service: 1.07
        Total: 108.93
     Last run: 1401869964
   Config retrieval: 16.49
   Mongodb database: 3.99
         File: 76.60
   Mongodb user: 9.43
Version:
       Config: 1401868442
       Puppet: 3.4.3
```

This doesn't seem very helpful to me, as the amount of time total's 108 seconds, so where have the other 1385 seconds gone?

Throughout, Puppet seems to be hammering the box, using up a lot of CPU, but still doesn't seem to advance. The memory it uses seems to continually increase. When I kick off the command, top looks like this:

```
Cpu(s): 10.2%us,  2.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 85.5%id,  2.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4956928k total,  2849296k used,  2107632k free,    63464k buffers
Swap:   950264k total,    26688k used,   923576k free,   445692k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
28486 root      20   0  439m 334m 3808 R 97.5  6.9   2:02.92 puppet
   22 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  1.3  0.0   0:07.55 kblockd/0
18276 mongod    20   0  788m  31m 3040 S  1.3  0.6   2:31.82 mongod
20756 jboss-as  20   0 3081m 1.5g  21m S  1.3 31.4   7:13.15 java
20930 elastics  20   0 2340m 236m 6580 S  1.0  4.9   1:44.80 java
  266 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   0:03.85 jbd2/dm-0-8
22717 vagrant   20   0 98.0m 2252 1276 S  0.3  0.0   0:01.81 sshd
28762 vagrant   20   0 15036 1228  932 R  0.3  0.0   0:00.10 top
    1 root      20   0 19364 1180  964 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.86 init
```

To me, this seems fine, there's over 2GB of available memory and plenty of available swap. I have a max open files limit of 1024.

About 10-15 minutes later, still no advance in the console output, but top looks like this:

```
Cpu(s): 11.2%us,  1.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 86.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%s
Mem:   4956928k total,  3834376k used,  1122552k free,    64248k buffers
Swap:   950264k total,    24408k used,   925856k free,   445728k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
28486 root      20   0 1397m 1.3g 3808 R 99.6 26.7  15:16.19 puppet
18276 mongod    20   0  788m  31m 3040 R  1.7  0.6   2:45.03 mongod
20756 jboss-as  20   0 3081m 1.5g  21m S  1.3 31.4   7:25.93 java
20930 elastics  20   0 2340m 238m 6580 S  0.7  4.9   1:52.03 java
 8486 root      20   0  308m  952  764 S  0.3  0.0   0:06.03 VBoxService
```

As you can see, puppet is now using a lot more of the memory, and it seems to continue in this fashion. The box it's building has 5GB of RAM, so I wouldn't have expected it to have memory issues. However, further down the line, after a long wait, I do get "Cannot allocate memory - fork(2)"

Running unlimit -a, I get:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 38566
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Which, again looks fine to me...

To be honest, I'm completely at a loss as to how to go about solving this, or what is causing it.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

So I managed to fix this eventually... It came down to using recurse with a file directive for a large directory. The target directory in question contained around 2GB worth of files, and puppet took a huge amount of time loading this into memory and doing it's hashes and comparisons. The first time I stood the server up, the directory was relatively empty so the check was quick, but then other resources were placed in it that increased its size massively, meaning subsequent runs took much longer.

The memory error that eventually was thrown was because, I can only assume, Puppet was loading the whole thing into memory in order to do its stuff...

I found a way around using the recurse function, and am now trying to avoid it like the plague...

Comment: On what OS is this box based? What is the Ruby version? Newer Ruby versions may behave better.

Comment: So i managed to fix this eventually... It came down to using recurse with a file directive for a large directory. The target directory in question contained around 2GB worth of files, and puppet took a huge amount of time loading this into memory and doing it's hashes and comparisons. The memory error that eventually was thrown was because, i can only assume, puppet was loading the whole thing into memory in order to do its stuff... I found a way around using the recurse function, and am now trying to avoid it like the plague.

Comment: Try `checksum => none` for such recursive file resources.

Comment: Ah ok, great thanks. I've now removed the need for the recursion, but i'll bear that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the problem with the `recurse` parameter on the file type is that it checks every single file's checksum, which on a massive directory adds up real quick.

As Felix suggests, using `checksum => none` is one way to fix it, another is to accomplish the task you're trying to do (say chmod or chown a whole directory) with an `exec` performing the native task, with an unless to check if it's already been done.

Something like:

```
define check_mode($mode) {
  exec { "/bin/chmod $mode $name":
    unless => "/bin/sh -c '[ $(/usr/bin/stat -c %a $name) == $mode ]'",
  }
}
```

Taken from http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/File_Permission_Check_Patterns